# onmouseover event to show and hide scrollbar of side menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: HelpImage]I want my HTML page to show the side menu scroll bar on on-mouse-over event. I can hide this side bar using below code in CSS.

```
.side-ul {
    height: 550px;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

but I am being unable to show it on-mouse-over event. I tried using

```
<div onmouseover="mouseMoveFunction()">
    overflow=auto;
</div>
function mouseOver(){
    return $("side-ul-over").start();
}
.side-ul-over{
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow:auto;
} <!-- This is CSS part -->
```

I am very new to HTML and CSS. Any help would be appreciated.

```
nav.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0099ff;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 10px;

}
```

Comment: try pure CSS: `.side-ul:hover { overflow: auto; }`

Comment: I tried using .side-ul:hover { overflow: auto; } does any more changes require in function. I have an snapshot of screen but to share that I would need 10 rep.

Comment: I have updated my question and added sidebar code. Please check

Comment: Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hz8xt6sg/

Comment: I didn't get it. Didn't it work with :hover ? It should have, I think.

Comment: Amazing Bro @kalpeshpatel ... its working now. Can anyone tell me how to mark it answer or close it?

Comment: @BRAIN,  I have added inline snippet in my answer below. You can click on 'Right' tick in front of answer to accept iy. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code works for me:

```css
.scrolling_list {
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.scrolling_list:hover {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class='scrolling_list'>
   <li>Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi, euismod in, pharetra a, ultricies in, diam. Sed arcu. Cras consequat.</li>
   <li>Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus.</li>
   <li>Phasellus ultrices nulla quis nibh. Quisque a lectus. Donec consectetuer ligula vulputate sem tristique cursus. Nam nulla quam, gravida non, commodo a, sodales sit amet, nisi.</li>
   <li>Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</li>
   <li>Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi, euismod in, pharetra a, ultricies in, diam. Sed arcu. Cras consequat.</li>
   <li>Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus.</li>
   <li>Phasellus ultrices nulla quis nibh. Quisque a lectus. Donec consectetuer ligula vulputate sem tristique cursus. Nam nulla quam, gravida non, commodo a, sodales sit amet, nisi.</li>
   <li>Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</li>
<li>Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi, euismod in, pharetra a, ultricies in, diam. Sed arcu. Cras consequat.</li>
   <li>Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus.</li>
   <li>Phasellus ultrices nulla quis nibh. Quisque a lectus. Donec consectetuer ligula vulputate sem tristique cursus. Nam nulla quam, gravida non, commodo a, sodales sit amet, nisi.</li>
   <li>Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</li>
   <li>Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi, euismod in, pharetra a, ultricies in, diam. Sed arcu. Cras consequat.</li>
   <li>Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus.</li>
   <li>Phasellus ultrices nulla quis nibh. Quisque a lectus. Donec consectetuer ligula vulputate sem tristique cursus. Nam nulla quam, gravida non, commodo a, sodales sit amet, nisi.</li>
   <li>Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</li>
   <li>Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi, euismod in, pharetra a, ultricies in, diam. Sed arcu. Cras consequat.</li>
   <li>Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus.</li>
   <li>Phasellus ultrices nulla quis nibh. Quisque a lectus. Donec consectetuer ligula vulputate sem tristique cursus. Nam nulla quam, gravida non, commodo a, sodales sit amet, nisi.</li>
   <li>Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</li>
   <li>Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi, euismod in, pharetra a, ultricies in, diam. Sed arcu. Cras consequat.</li>
   <li>Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus.</li>
   <li>Phasellus ultrices nulla quis nibh. Quisque a lectus. Donec consectetuer ligula vulputate sem tristique cursus. Nam nulla quam, gravida non, commodo a, sodales sit amet, nisi.</li>
   <li>Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</li>
<li>Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi, euismod in, pharetra a, ultricies in, diam. Sed arcu. Cras consequat.</li>
   <li>Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus.</li>
   <li>Phasellus ultrices nulla quis nibh. Quisque a lectus. Donec consectetuer ligula vulputate sem tristique cursus. Nam nulla quam, gravida non, commodo a, sodales sit amet, nisi.</li>
   <li>Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</li>
   <li>Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi, euismod in, pharetra a, ultricies in, diam. Sed arcu. Cras consequat.</li>
   <li>Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus.</li>
   <li>Phasellus ultrices nulla quis nibh. Quisque a lectus. Donec consectetuer ligula vulputate sem tristique cursus. Nam nulla quam, gravida non, commodo a, sodales sit amet, nisi.</li>
   <li>Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it following way using CSS:

```
.side-ul:hover {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Check using JQuery:

```js
$(".side-ul").mouseover(function(){$(this).css("overflow","auto");});
$(".side-ul").mouseout(function(){$(this).css("overflow","hidden");});
```

```css
.side-ul {
    height: 260px;
    width:200px;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="side-ul" onmouseover="mouseOver()">
    overflow=auto;<br/>
    overflow=auto;<br/>v
    overflow=auto;<br/>voverflow=auto;<br/>overflow=auto;<br/>
    overflow=auto;<br/>overflow=auto;<br/>overflow=auto;<br/>overflow=auto;<br/>
    overflow=auto;<br/>overflow=auto;<br/>overflow=auto;<br/>overflow=auto;<br/>overflow=auto;<br/>overflow=auto;<br/>overflow=auto;<br/>overflow=auto;<br/>overflow=auto;<br/>overflow=auto;<br/>overflow=auto;<br/>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.